# Remote update of multiple websites and DB's of the same application

Tags: sql, iis, asp.net-core, updates, remote-access

I have developed a net core application that is an API that receives data from various devices in the field. The API has a small website in the application to manage the API (all of this is on IIS). The data from the API is stored in a SQL Server Express DB (2017). On the same server is a WinForms application that takes data from the database and creates CSV files and stores them in a folder in the web application. This is done so there is FTP access for the CSV files to be pushed or pulled.

The customer has now said they want to take the whole application as described above and put it on mini PC’s to put on customer sites, there could end up being hundreds of mini PC's with the application installed. I have tested it on the mini pc’s and it works fine.

What I want to understand, is how can update the database an the API/web application remotely for all the mini PC’s (in one hit). By this I mean, if the customer deploys 10 mini PC’s with the application as described above and a year later I have an update to the database table, SPROCs etc and added a feature to the API and website, how can I get them to update themselves without going into each mini PC to do the update. As I am using Entity Framework, perhaps the API/Web application can deal with the database. The Winforms application I can deal with.

In my mind, I have something in the API/web application that checks to see if there is an update, (similar to a WinForms application), then updates itself and refreshes IIS. I also have the same principle in mind for the DB.

I have done some research and cannot find anything that makes sense in terms of doing this.

I have been thinking of FTP'ing the new site to all of the mini PC's, but there may be firewall issues on the customer site, port 80 will always be open though.

I would appreciate learning any techniques or technology that can do this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue in the above approach is the firewall issue with the mini pcs. Few users may have the external connections blocked. 
The simple way i can think of is host a normal website and have each user access to it to use and maintain everything at a single place. 
This will help you manage the db, the api forms or anything else in terms of security or enhancements.